# Leave open pop-up window when jumping Error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

The situation is that I have a bootstrap modal where I have a form to login, if the user is inactive or password was incorrect, jump a mistake, but when you click to log in if you get this error window isn't open for show it, and so the user isn't aware of the passing.

**I would like to know how can I do that when I skip the error I open the modal to display it.**

```css
nav ul{
 list-style:none;
 margin:2em 0;
}

nav li{
 margin-right:2em;
 display:inline-block;
}

.modal-body, .modal-header{
 background:#2c3338;
 color:#606468;
}

#signin{
 width:auto;
 height:auto;
}

#signin span{
 background-color:#363b41;
 border-radius:3px 0px 0px 3px;
 -moz-border-radius:3px 0px 0px 3px;
 -webkit-border-radius:3px 0px 0px 3px;
 color:#606468;
 display:block;
 float:left;
 height:50px;
 line-height:50px;
 text-align:center;
 width:50px;
}

#signin input{
 height:50px;
}

#signin input{
 background-color:#3b4148;
 border-radius:0px 3px 3px 0px;
 -moz-border-radius:0px 3px 3px 0px;
 -webkit-border-radius:0px 3px 3px 0px;
 color:#606468;
 margin:0 0 2% 5%;
 padding:0 16px;
 width:198px;
}

#signin input:focus{
 border:2px solid #785da1;
 outline:none;
    box-shadow:0 0 10px #785da1;
}

#signin input[type="submit"]{
 width:280px;
 height:55px;
 border-radius:3px;
 -moz-border-radius:3px;
 -webkit-border-radius:3px;
 background-color:#624291;
 color:#eee;
 font-weight:bold;
 margin:2% 0 2% 2%;
}

#signin input[type="submit"]:hover{
 background-color:#7842A6;
}

#signin a{
 color:#eee;
 text-decoration:none;
}

#signin a:hover{
 text-decoration:underline;
}

#signin p{
 width:300px;
 height:auto;
}

#signin input{
 border:none;
 font-family:'Calibri';
 font-size:14px;
 line-height:1.5em;
 padding:0;
 -webkit-appearance:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" lang="es-es">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font-awesome-4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
  <link href="css/css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/icSquared_v1.0.css"/>
  <title>SSSS!</title>
 </head>
<body>
<?php
 include 'fn.php';
 iniciarSesion();

 $msg = "";
 if(isset($_GET['miss']))
    {
        if($_GET['miss']=="1")
        {
           $msg= '<p class="text-danger text-center small" style="margin-bottom: 0;"> No existe este usuario con esta contraseña.. </p>';
        }
  elseif($_GET['miss']=="2")
        {
           $msg= '<p class="text-danger text-center small" style="margin-bottom: 0;"> Este usuario esta inactivo. </p>';
        }
    }
?>
<div>
 <header>
        <nav role="navigation" class="noround navbar-inverse">
            <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
     <span class="sr-only"> Barra de navegación</span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
   </div>
     
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left" style="margin:10px 0 10px 0">
                    <a href="index.php"><img src="fotos/logoH.png" /></a>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="registro.php"> Registrate <span class="fa fa-user-plus" style="font-size:16px; margin-top:5px"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#modalLogin" data-target="#modalLogin" data-toggle="modal"> Identificate <span class="fa fa-user" style="font-size:16px; margin-top:5px"></span><span class="caret"></span></a></li>
                </ul>
   </div>
        </nav>
 </header>
  
  </div>

<div class="modal fade" id="modalLogin" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times white"></i></button>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body text-center">
    <?php echo $msg; ?>
    <form action="action.php?action=login" method="post" class="form" id="signin">
      <div class="form-group">
      <p style="margin-left:4%"><span class="fa fa-user"></span>
      <input type="text" placeholder="ejemplo@ejemplo.com" name="emailLog" required class="form-control" style="padding-left:16px;" /></p>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
      <p style="margin-left:4%"><span class="fa fa-lock"></span>
      <input type="password" placeholder="contraseña" name="passwd" required class="form-control" style="padding-left:16px;" /></p>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
      <p class="text-center"><a href="">Has olvidado la contraseña?</a></p>
      <p style="height:70px;"><input type="submit" class="btn" id="enviar" value="ENTRAR" /></p>
      </div>
    </form>
    <p>No eres miembro?<a href=""> Registrate Ahora </a><span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span></p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<script src="js/jquery-1.12.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't need to put my "action.php", i know php and I have it right, when I process the form if it has an error is spent by the URL via GET, **I need to know how to make the window opens to display the error**

THANK YOU VERY MUCH TO ALL :)